# Which word processor has best compatibility with the doc(x) formats?

Tags: word-documents

I'm looking at LibreOffice Writer, Abiword or Calligra Words. Which has the best compatibility with docx/doc format?

Comment: For which **Ubuntu** version? How specific are your requirements?  Are you using Excel or Word documents with specific/advanced MS Office features?

Comment: I use both Ubuntu and Lubuntu 12.04. I am mainly concerned about Word documents, I may need some advanced features rather than just a plain document, but all for personal use, not for colaboration. I just want to make sure that I can for example create a Word document at home and be able to edit it on a public PC for example, that does not have MSOffice, without losing formatting and with complete features, rather than Skydrive Web Apps, GDocs or Zoho which I've tried already but didn't convince me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried all of them and they all work OK.  But I personally like Libreoffice, and it come on top in the reviews.

Comment: I am more inclined to LibreOffice as well for being a complete suite and similar to MSOffice, which is basically the only I've ever used... I guess with a little tweaks such as installing MSfonts on ubuntu and using .doc instead of .docx the compatibility between them must be better.

Answer (score 3):

The new LibreOffice 4.1 seemed load docx file more correctly than the previous version (4.0) - which is a big deal for LibreOffice at this version, but for loading pptx file both version seemed not changed a lot (text in textbox still rendered bigger than it should), one thing helpful on my experience is in 4.1 pptx file can be surfed faster.

Abiword is faster than LibreOffice, but Abiword still has compatibility issue in handling Open Document Text files, I've experienced this issue but I don't know whether this issues is still present in the latest Abiword version or not.

You can also try Kingsoft office, a free proprietary office that works on Linux.
I just tried it few minutes ago and it open .docx and .pptx more correctly than LibreOffice 4.1.